# Converting from object_id to something useful (name, email, etc) in Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm on my first Ruby on Rails project and I'm trying to display a list of users in a select box. I want to show all of the users (except the currently logged-in one).

I have that part down right now, using this code in my model, view, and controller:

Request Controller:

```
def new
  @request = Request.new
  @users = User.without_user(current_user)
end
```

New Requests View:

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :user_id, 'Select user' %>
  <br />
  <%= select_tag(:user_id, options_for_select(@users)) %>
</div>
```

User Model:

```
scope :without_user,
      lambda{|user| user ? {:conditions =>[":id != ?", user.id]} : {} }
```

This all works well, but my select box is populated with the object_id of the user. How can I convert that object_id into a first name/last name combination, for example? I tried doing something like:

```
<%= select_tag(:user_id, options_for_select(@users.first_name)) %>
```

but that gave me an 'undefined method error.' What would be the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the select_tag of your view, you can have:

```
<%= select_tag(:user_id, options_from_collection_for_select(@users, :id, :first_name)) %>
```

This would display the first_name and when the user selects one of the options, the `user id` is what is filled into the `value` attribute for the select tag.

If you would like to display the full name, you can have a method in your user model:

```
def full_name
  return first_name + " " + last_name
end
```

And, in your view:

```
<%= select_tag(:user_id, options_from_collection_for_select(@users, :id, :full_name)) %>
```

You can find more information about `options_from_collection_for_select` [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_from_collection_for_select)

Comment: This is excellent! Exactly what I needed. Thanks for the link on the `options_from_collection_for_select` method. I'd never heard of it before!

Answer (score 0):

What you need is `options_from_collection_for_select`.

In your case it would be:

`<%= select_tag(:user_id, options_from_collection_for_select(@users, :id, :first_name)) %>`

You can read more about it and other helpers [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_from_collection_for_select)

Comment: Thanks for the reply and the link to helpers. Aayush got me pointed in the right direction, but thanks again!